# advanced settings and default settings in different screens

Tags: settings, flow

I have this step by step configuration flow, to help people create an object.  The idea is to show the required configurations on the surface, and more advanced settings, below this layer - because most of the users will not even know what those configurations will do ( I need to show them because they do exist, even tho they are for ultra-advanced users, let’s say 5% of the users).
[image]

My question Is about having those advanced settings on a different screen. Imagine you change some configurations on this panel, and then you go back to the default settings panel and when you try to open the object, something is not working.  You go through these steps and everything looks fine… but what is messing everything up is an advanced configuration that is hidden behind this first surface.

Can you give me some examples on how to flag, in the default settings screen,  that I have advanced configurations set?

Is this a bad way of building this flow?

Answer (score 2):

It could work, but a better way is to keep your settings in one screen.

**Use a show/hide advanced settings toggle.**

This way the user can see all settings in one view. It is easier to compare settings because the user does not have to switch screens and remember his settings from the previous screen.

[There's a chance the user will forget](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/short-term-memory-and-web-usability/) his settings and has to switch back and forth a lot.

> Summary: The human brain is not optimized for the abstract thinking
>   and data memorization that websites often demand. Many usability
>   guidelines are dictated by cognitive limitations.

**See image below.**

The user sees basic settings as a default but can toggle advanced settings by clicking the 'show advanced' link. Also provide a message warning users about the advanced settings.

[image]

**An example is Plex Media Server.**

Users can run the server without knowledge of advanced settings. It will work, but there's a 'show/hide advanced' toggle if users want to use the advanced settings.

[image]