# What's the best way to denote that a field in a form is a pro feature?

Tags: forms, product-design

I need to tell the user that he/she can use the field in a form only if he/she is a pro user. I thought about something like this:

[image]

But I'm not very sure if replacing the BROWSE button with PRO is good idea.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pro will be missed because: 1) it looks like a regular button at first glance
2) why the heck does this say pro? *CLICK*
3) why is it disabled if I can't enable it in this current UI *confused*
4) there isn't more information to help me understand what pro is other than it is a button and I have no inclination how it helps me

Comment: Also how many pro features are on this page? Just that logo?

Comment: Shouldn't that be something you set in a role? Or is it registerless form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a padlock above the image where the logo would look. 
And when the user clicks, it will open the modal with the pro options.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frUrhT.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**EDIT:** Changed Unlock to You need to be a pro-member...

Comment: I like this, but why are you saying unlock? Someone actually has to click that to figure out what that is. Why not instead say "You need to be a pro-member in order to use this feature. **Become a pro member now.**"

Comment: Good comment, I agree with you. I'll edit my post

Answer (score 3):

I would not replace 'browse' with 'pro' since pro is not the right label for indicating the action for when the user clicks the button.

**Basic and advanced settings**

Perhaps you could have a label above the pro settings called 'advanced settings'.

I came across a similar situation yesterday that might help you. [See the question here.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107445/advanced-settings-and-default-settings-in-different-screens/107447#107447)

The idea is that you only show the basic settings and let the user show/hide advanced settings. Show them that the advanced settings are, well... advanced, so that they are warned.